# Active Record select field on included sub query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-6

I have some sql that I am trying to convert to ActiveRecord

The sql looks like

```sql
      select type.name, sum(order.sub_total)
      from orders order
      join order_types type on type.id = order_type_id
      group by type.name
```

I have this mostly working except that I cannot figure out how to select `type.name`

```rb
    Order.
      select("sum(sub_total)").
      joins(:order_type).
      group("order_type_id`")
```

I'm thinking it should be something like:

```rb
    Order.
      select("order_type.name, sum(sub_total)").
      joins(:order_type).
      group("order_type_id`")
```

but it's not aware of what `order_type.name` is in this context so this fails.

Anyone know how I can do this in a way that still feels "railsy"

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```rb
    Order.
      select("order_types.name, sum(orders.sub_total).
      joins(:order_type).
      group("order_types.name")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```rb
grouped_orders = Order.select("order_types.name name, sum(orders.sub_total) sub_total")
                      .joins(:order_type)
                      .group("order_types.name")
```

And then, you can list the order names like this:

```rb
grouped_orders.map(&:name)
```